# Tzaloa 2015 game problem (piles with $1,2,4 \dots 2^{19}$ coins each)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, contest-math, game-theory, binary

We have $20$ piles with $1,2,4,8\dots 2^{19}$ coins repectively and two players. In each turn a player must select five piles that have at least one coin and remove exactly one coin from each. Player $A$ begins and player $B$ follows. The first player who cannot select five non-empty piles loses and the other one wins.

Which player has the winning strategy and which is the strategy? I feel like there should be an easy strategy which comes from some invariant but every strategy I have tried runs into complications at the later stages of the game. One thing which may or may not help is that each pile has more coins than all of the smaller piles combined. I have tried recursion, and a strategy which relies on making sure the piles that are emptied are the $16$ smallest and always trying to keep a number of coins that is $0\bmod 6$ on the $16$ smallest piles, however this strategy fails at the end.

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand this completely.  At each stage, each player selects exactly five non-empty piles and removes *exactly* one coin from each?  So that this game, if played at an ordinary pace, would take an enormous time to complete?  (I'm not raising that as any kind of objection; I just want to make sure I understand this right.)

Comment: Yes, it would take a while.

Comment: A slight variant on the original invariant you mentioned (which seemed only valid in the beginning), it seems like no matter what move player 1 makes, player 2 can make sure that every pile has at least as many coins as the pile ahead of it. I'm not sure if that helps, i.e. if player 2 can guarantee that this strategy will eventually lead to player 1 having 4 piles or less to choose from.

Comment: Can you explain why you tried a strategy that tries to maintain $0 \bmod 6$ on the $16$ smallest piles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** By parity, Player B can guarantee that he can duplicate Player A's move.

The only concern is if Player A drew from the 1 pile. Deal with that.

Comment: Player $A$ can win. He removes coins from piles of sizes $1,2^{17},2^{18},2^{19},2^{20}$. This leaves all the piles which can actually be deleted with an even number of coins (because the four largest piles can never be deleted). From now on player $A$ can copy player $B$'s moves. In this way player $B$ can never delete a pile since he will always leave the "deletable" piles with an odd number of coins each.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo:  yes, you are right.

Comment: @RossMillikan I can finally die in peace !